# Wald's second equation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

We have a random walk $S_N=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$ where $X_i$ are i.i.d with $0<E(X_i)<\infty$ and $N$ is a stopping time.
What is the "exact" second equation of Wald ?

I've seen different results and sometimes they are contradictory.

Thank you

Comment: Could you state the different results you saw?

Comment: I've seen $E(S_N-E(X_1)N)^2=V(X_1)E(N)$ in this lecture note [link](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~peledron/Teaching/RW_and_BM_2011/scribe2.pdf&sa=U&ei=QfPfUbOkApCM4gSmn4GQBA&ved=0CBwQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNFldBPau1vxXbQPp53FvrB3w3pZYA). I've also seen $E(S_N^2)=V(X_1)E(N)$ when $E(X_1)=0$, the place of the square is very strange in the first case.

Comment: I see again $E(S_N−E(X_1)N)2=V(X_1)E(_N)$ with the external power 2 at this [link](http://books.google.fr/books?id=_5Xqo02nzO0C&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=wald%27s+second+lemma&source=bl&ots=g6zYLWMWUG&sig=XVm2-hvH0DV7J4z1Au3WTflvGCE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TfffUc2cN4j_4QTMjIGQCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wald%27s%20second%20lemma&f=false).

Comment: I notice that sometimes a same scribe uses indifferently the parentheses either for the mean $E(.)$ or to precise the association of variables (and by omiting the parentheses for $E$)...

Comment: @DavideGiraudo What do you think about the place of this square ? Maybe it's a variance and the square has to be applied on $(S_n-E(X_1)N)$ but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 3):

All the results mean 
$$\mathbb E\left[\left(S_N-\mathbb E(X_1)\cdot N\right)^2\right]=\operatorname{Var}(X_1)\cdot\mathbb E(N).$$

Comment: You are welcome.